# Win7 won't resume from sleep/hibernation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, hibernate

I read many posts about this problem, but most of them consider the user a linux expert who knows what he's talking about :/ I would really appreciate it if someone can solve this problem for a beginner like me.

I have installed Linux on my laptop with dual boot. When I power my PC I get to the grub screen and can decide if I want Ubuntu or Win7. However, whenever Windows 7 goes to sleep/hibernation - when I open the laptop up again and "wake" it - it does not succeed in resuming the previous Win7 session. Any data that was open is lost, and I must restart the PC.

I'm guessing this has to do with the dual boot and grub.. if anyone could help me with this that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest procedure to get rid of the Windows 7 hibernation problem is to boot into Windows, click the start button, type `cmd` and right-click on the icon on the top of your menu, left-click on "Run as an administrator", enter the admin username/password **or** click "yes" to continue, and type `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` and all your Windows 7 hibernation problems will be gone!

Comment: Don't thank me!  Once you've got enough reputation on this site, upvote my answer!  ;-)